# Herstein Problem No.7 Page 102

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

let $G$ be  a group of order $30$ .How many non-isomorphic groups of order $30 $ are there?

Before doing this I have shown that every Sylow 3 and Sylow 5 subgroup is normal in G and G has a normal subgroup of order 15.

**Using these information Herstein has asked to classify all groups of order 30**.

I am stuck here.Any help

**Note:**
I don't know why this has been marked as duplicate because the duplicate question has answers which don't suit the way I want to solve the problem or rather the author has asked to solve it which i have mentioned explicitly in my question

Comment: No Matt Samuel, they are four: $Z_{30},Z_5\times S_3,D_{15},Z_3\times D_5$. Good effort though.

Comment: $Z_5\times S_3$ has $3$ elements of order $2$. $D_{15}$ has $16$ elements of order $2$ and $Z_3\times D_5$ has $6$ elements of order $2$. How can they be isomorphic?

Comment: Hint: in the non-abelian case ($G \not\cong \Bbb Z_{30}$), consider the possible number of elements of order $2$ (which is the same as the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups). This number must be an odd divisor of $15$ greater than $1$. Then show each  possibility actually occurs by considering the action via conjugation of an element of order $2$ on the normal subgroup of order $15$ (if these two groups are $P,Q$, then $G = PQ$).

Comment: @Gamamal I found a third automorphism, so now I agree. Sorry for the unnecessary argument.

Comment: @MattSamuel No need to apologize, it is a good topic to discuss in my opinion.

Comment: @MattSamuel Please consider your vote

Comment: BTW, it's only partially relevant, but https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf is a great read.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the only possibilities for the number of $2$-subgroups are $1$, $3$, $5$, or $15$. If there is one $2$-subgroup, then obviously the group is $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$. Otherwise the group is nonabelian since it contains a subgroup that is not normal.

From now on we let $x$ be an element of order $2$ and we let $y$ be an element of order $15$. We know that the subgroup $\langle x,y\rangle$ is the entire group, hence every element can be expressed as $x^ay^k$ for some $a\in \{0,1\}$ and some $0\leq k\leq 14$. Thus in particular we have $yx=xy^n$ for some $n$, meaning $yxy^{-1}=xy^{n-1}$. Thus for any $m$ we have $y^mx=xy^{nm}$, so 
$$y^mxy^{-m}=xy^{nm-m}=xy^{m(n-1)}$$

Since every subgroup of order $2$ is conjugate by the Sylow theorems, every element of order $2$ is conjugate to every other element of order $2$. I want to show that the conjugating element (conjugating $x$) can always be taken to be a power of $y$. To see this, suppose instead we need to use $xy^k$ for some $k$. We have
$$xy^kxy^{-k}x=x(xy^{k(n-1)})x=y^{k(n-1)}x=xy^{kn(n-1)}=y^{kn}xy^{-kn}$$
Thus we could have conjugated by a power of $y$ in the first place. The goal then is to match the number of Sylow subgroups to the number of conjugates of $x$ by picking $n$.

Notice that if $yx=xy^n$, then $xyx=y^n$, and hence $y=x(xyx)x=xy^nx=y^{n^2}$. Thus we must have that $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{15}$.

Suppose there are $15$ subgroups of order $2$. Then the elements $y^mxy^{-m}=xy^{m(n-1)}$ are all different. This means $n-1$ must be relatively prime to $15$, meaning $n=2,3,5,8,9,12$, or $14$. Only $14$ squares to $1$ mod $15$, so the one and only possible group satisfies $yx=xy^{14}$.

Suppose there are $5$ subgroups of order $2$. Then there are five distinct elements $y^mxy^{-m}=xy^{m(n-1)}$. This means that $\gcd(n-1,15)=3$, or $n=4,7,10,13$, and by the square condition we must have that $n=4$, so $yx=xy^4$.

Suppose finally that there are $3$ subgroups of order $2$. Then there are three distinct elements $y^mxy^{-m}=xy^{m(n-1)}$. This means that $\gcd(n-1,15)=5$, so $n=6,11$, but only $11$ squares to $1$ mod $15$, so we have $yx=xy^{11}$.

Thus we have exhausted all four possibilities.

Comment: I have one problem sir; how is $y^mx=xy^{nm}$

Comment: Normally I'd be out like a light at this time but you're in luck, this has been a sleepless night. The equation you quote can be verified Inductively. I'm sure you'll see how from the example: $y^2x=yxy^n=xy^ny^n=xy^{2n}$.

Comment: yes I got it ;sorry to disturb

Comment: @learnmore no worries. It's true that my phone vibrated, but I was awake already and if it had woken me it would have been my own fault for leaving it on. This is a global site, who knows what time zone others are in? Certainly you shouldn't have to worry about that when leaving a comment because there's no way to err on the side of caution without asking.

Comment: One problem sir; how did you get that $n$ has the following possibilities as $n=4,7,10,13$ in the different cases

Comment: @learnmore By the greatest common divisor conditions. Those are all nonnegative integers less than 15 such that, in the case you mention, $n-1$ and 15 have a gcd.of 3.

Comment: What I am not getting is that if number of Sylow 2 subgroups is 15 then why is $n-1$ prime to 15;$n^2\equiv1 $ is clear

Comment: also why inthe second and third case you get $\gcd(n-1,15)=3,5$ respectively I dont understand

Comment: @learnmore we need 15 different elements of the form $xy^{m(n-1)}$. This means the multiples of $n-1$ should hit all remainders mod 15, so $n-1$ generates the cyclic group of order 15, meaning it is relatively prime.

Comment: The key is really how many different elements of the form $xy^{m(n-1)}$ you get. The number of different elements is the quotient of 15 by the gcd. This is the order of the subgroup generated by $y^{n-1}$.